# Selenium standalone server fails in production mode - Grails

Tags: selenium, grails

I have a web application written using Grails that's failing in production mode when trying to fire up Selenium standalone server.

Here's the error:

```
 2017-12-04 10:04:52,905 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR 
 errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ClassNotFoundException occurred when 
 processing request: [GET] /Diversotron-0.1/api/edit
 com.google.common.base.Function. Stacktrace follows:
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2585)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1906)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
    at diversotron.PropotronService.setPropotron(PropotronService.groovy:29)
    at diversotron.ApiController.edit(ApiController.groovy:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Line 29 is this:

```
 WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://123.456.78.910:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities)
```

This works perfectly fine in debug mode. Anyone have any ideas? (IP address hidden for privacy)

Answer (score 0):

Use **`FirefoxOptions`** to merge the capabilities through [**`org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html) as follows :

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("...", true);
capabilities.setCapability("...", true);
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.merge(capabilities);
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), options);
```

Comment: I'm using Chrome but anyway, it's failing at this line:  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()

Comment: @Sulteric ChromeOptions failing means we need to look at the imports and jar compatibility.

Comment: Check the updated Answer for the JavaDoc link for `org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities`

Comment: It's the JavaDoc of [`org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html). Nothing to download in addition. Updated `Selenium Client Jars` will take care of it.

Comment: This stuff is in in 3.8.1. Downloaded that, added the libraries to my project.  options.merge(capabilities); still fails